# SQL select all records if at least one record fulfils a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have several tables

```
table1
-------------------------
|id|  rec    | other_rec|
-------------------------
|1 | record1 | record6  |
|2 | record2 | record8  |
|3 | record4 | record0  |
|4 | record5 | record2  |
|n |   ...   |   ...    |
------------------------
```

and a second table

```
table2
-------------------------------------------------
|id|  table_nr_1_foreign_key | rec_1  | rec_2   |
-------------------------------------------------
|1 | table_nr_1_key_1        |record1 | rt1     |
|2 | table_nr_1_key_2        |record2 | rt2     |
|3 | table_nr_1_key_2        |record4 | rt3     |
|4 | table_nr_1_key_3        |record5 | rt4     |
|5 | table_nr_1_key_2        |record6 | rt5     |
|n | table_nr_1_key_n        |  ...   |   ...   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

and an SQL query

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.rec,
       t.other_rec,
       t2.rec_1
FROM table1 t1
JOIN ...[other table]
   and ...[conditions start]
   and ...
   and ...[conditions end]
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t.id = table_nr_1_foreign_key
AND t2.rec_2 = any(array['rt2'])
where ...[other condition]
```

now I want to select **all** records from table2 which have a corresponding foreign key in a table1
if and only if at least one record exists in a table2 that points to a table1.

so I want

```
data1,..., rt2
data1,..., rt3
data1,..., rt5
...
```

to be selected

but all I get is

```
data1,..., rt2
```

**Update no 1.**

with my inexperience I failed to accomplish selection with one sql and wrote two sql queries instead

1. for data selection for a main record (table 1)
2. the other for selecting all records from a table 2 (using in([list
   of ids]))

This question can be closed / deleted.

Comment: `... from table2 which have a corresponding foreign key in a table2 ...` <<-- From table1 ? typo? [and the answer is: use `EXISTS(...)`]

Comment: where should I put it? Should I replace ANY with EXISTS?

Comment: `select all records from table2 t WHERE EXISTS(select * FROM table2 x [join table1 ...] where x.a=t.a and x.b='something')`